# Creating Path From SVG String in XML

Tags: android, xml, svg

I have an SVG XML File.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="400dp"
    android:height="400dp"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="400">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M0,0h400v400h-400z"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M-1.5,-1.5v403h403v-403H-1.5zM400,400H0V0h400V400z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M94,183.75a99.75,67.75 0,1 0,199.5 0a99.75,67.75 0,1 0,-199.5 0z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M398.5,1.5H1.5v397h397V1.5zM193.75,254.5C137.09,254.5 91,222.76 91,183.75S137.09,113 193.75,113c56.66,0 102.75,31.74 102.75,70.75S250.41,254.5 193.75,254.5z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

I need to convert all the Path PathData to Path like Move to, Line To Quad To in Android.
How can I convert XML Path Data to that?
I need to Convert Path Data String Move to, Line to Like that.

Comment: That's not an SVG XML file. It's an android VectorDrawable file. The path data already has move, line commands so M is a move command, V is a vertical line etc.